# add numpy arrays without knowing the shape

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to add values element-wise of a numpy array but I don't know the shape until the first element is added, so I wrote the following working code with an `if` statement:

```
import numpy as np

class Layer:

    def __init__(self):
        self.delta_weights = np.array([])

    def add_delta_weights(self, delta_weights):
        if(self.delta_weights.size > 0):
            self.delta_weights = self.delta_weights + delta_weights
        else:
            self.delta_weights = delta_weights
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to write the code above without the `if` statement? How can I initialize `self.delta_weights` so I can simply write:

```
def add_delta_weights(self, delta_weights):
    self.delta_weights = self.delta_weights + delta_weights
```

Comment: Usually in python we start with `x=None` and use a `if x is None:` test

Comment: @hpaulj oh yeah my bad! I change it to `None`, but the `if` statement is still around.

Comment: `setl.delta_weights = np.array([0])` is a shape (1,) array that broadcasts with any other shape.

Comment: That exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! where can I find the documentation of this? (feel free to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it)

Comment: @hpaulj any reason not to use `np.array(False)` or even `False` instead? I think it does mostly the same as your suggestion but leaves scalars alone and also preserves all (?)  numerical dtypes. The array version (vs. the pure `False`) has the advantage that it can handle "array-like" stuff like lists, but the disadvantage that it makes 0d arrays out of scalars.

Comment: @loopywalt, are you suggesting `False+np.array([1,2,3])`?  I'm assuming he whzts to add multiple numeric arrays which are all the same size (or at least broadcastable). I wouldn't mix dtypes unnecessarily.

Comment: @hpaulj that is exactly what I am suggesting, although, `0` and `array(0)` appear to work just the same except for booleans. Imagine, you have this snippet somewhere deep inside your project and at some point you run into memory problems and decide to switch from `float64` to `float32`. With `array([0])` chances are you'll spend a wee bit of time chasing after what on earth is switching your stuff back to `float64`. With `0` or `False` or `array(0)` or `array(False)` this won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

In general, having uninitialized state is bad practice. That is what constructors are for, and the existence of an object should imply its state is valid.

[Further reading](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/are-null-references-really-a-bad-thing)

---

You can use the constructor to make it clean:

```
import numpy as np


class Layer:
    def __init__(self, delta_weights: np.array):
        self._delta_weights = delta_weights

    def add_delta_weights(self, other: np.array):
        self._delta_weights += other
```

The very existence of a `layer = Layer(weights)` implies the internal state is valid.

Usage:

```
layer = Layer(np.zeros((5, 6, 7)))  # 1st call
layer.add_delta_weights((np.zeros((5, 6, 7))))  # consecutive calls
layer.add_delta_weights((np.zeros((5, 6, 7))))  # consecutive calls
layer.add_delta_weights((np.zeros((5, 6, 7))))  # consecutive calls
```

I assume your wrapping logic has some sense of "1st call" and "consecutive calls".

In general, [try to avoid if statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z43bmaMwagI).